# What does "and she them" mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Moaning Myrtle was crying noisily in her cubicle, but they were ignoring her, ***and she them***.

I guess it just means ***she was ignoring them too***. But I have never seen this kind of structure before. Is it common? Any other examples for this kind of structure? What does it truly mean?

-- From Harry Potter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you're exactly right about the meaning. This is an example of a kind of [ellipsis](https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-ellipsis.html), or leaving words out. It's commonly used for words that would repeat exactly in a single sentence, so

> I ate a banana, I ate a pear, and I ate an apple.

would usually omit all but the first "I ate":

> I ate a banana, a pear, and an apple.

Note that sometimes we also leave out the articles, even though they aren't exactly the same because of the a/an distinction.

In this case, the "expanded" version of the sentence would be

> Moaning Myrtle was crying noisily in her cubicle, but they were ignoring her, and she ***was ignoring*** them.

In this case the verb conjugation has changed because the subject of the two clauses is different. This is a little less common than omission when the subject of the clauses is the same, but it's not ungrammatical. One example is the stereotypical formal dialogue between lovers:

> A: I love you!
>   B: And I you!

B leaves out the verb "love" because A already said it. As you guessed, this is just a different way to say "I love you, too": by leaving out the verb, B acknowledges that it was just said by A.<sup>1</sup>

As an American, this particular kind of ellipsis feels a bit old-fashioned or British to me, so I'm not surprised that it's in a work by a British author. The linked article is from "Grammar and Style in British English", which offers another example where the subject changes:

> - **I was to take the east path and Steve was to take the west path**
>
> becomes –
>
> - **I was to take the east path and Steve, the west.**
>
> [by omitting words] that would appear twice in the full sentence. In our example, these are the words *was to take* and *path* –
>
> - **I *was to take* the east *path* and Steve *was to take* the west *path***.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The couple is so in love, A can finish B's sentences *before B even says them*!</sub>

Comment: "I ate a banana, a pear, and an apple." This example is useless here, as it does not show an ellipsis but a simple listing.

Comment: @MrLister No, the answer says that sometimes we _do_ leave out articles even though they’re different.

Comment: @rexkogitans There is no fundamental difference between a list of three clauses and a list of three noun phrases: they’re both lists. You can analyse the deverbed version here as an elliptical form of the full version, or you can analyse it as a verb with an NP object that consists of a lists; there is no possible way to say that it is definitely one or the other, so the example is perfectly valid.

Comment: see also *vice versa* (with similar [meaning](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vice%20versa) but different [grammar](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/vice-versa/))

Answer (score 4):

I would consider this ellipsis too, but a special kind of ellipsis, a rhetorical strategy to state a symmetrical relationship.

> We distrust them and they us.
>
> We don't trust them nor they us.
>
> We trust them and they us.
>
> They trust us and we them.

Similar:

... and she me.

... and I her.

....and they them.

... nor they them.

and so forth.